# Google app maker: How to secure sensitive data in server scripts?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an app with a server script function that is calling an API endpoint to retrieve a token passing a username/password. According to 'Google app maker' documentation, you can make you server script functions private by appending an 'underscore' at the end of the function name. I want to validate this by looking at the script before/after the 'underscore' is added. How can I find the location of the server side scripts in my browser? I've already inspected all of the js files listed, but I had no luck. Are there any recommendations for storing the credentials passed to retrieve a token?

```js
function getToken_(){

  var securityModel = {"username":"serviceusername","password":"servicepassword"};

  var options = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(securityModel)
  };

  var tokenResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://myapiurlhere/token', options);

  return tokenResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that searching for the server script in your browser is not exactly what is meant in the documentation. Instead, take a look a **[this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805378/google-script-run-xx-is-not-a-function-error/52805847#52805847)** experienced by another user.

Now, in regards to storing the token obtained... you can use the [*PropertiesService*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setProperty(String,String)) to store and get that value whenever you want.

To store it, all you need to do is:

```
var token = getToken_();
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.setProperty('token', token);
```

After you save it, if you need to retrieve it, all you need to do is:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var token= userProperties.getProperty('token');
console.log(token);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @morfinismo. I'm trying to prevent any user from being able to get a hold of the securityModel object, which contains the user name and password to authenticate. if I use PropertiesService to store the securityModel, would any user be able to inspect the script using the developer tools and get a hold of the username and password?

Comment: @jorgeAChacon I'm not sure. So far I've inspected and was not able to get the information from the developer tools. I did a thorough research on the dev tools. I think its pretty safe.